# VBA vbWednesday Not Working

Tags: vba, excel

This has always worked for me to get me the current week's Thursday date.

This week it's giving me problems and showing last week's Thursday.

Can someone help me understand why this is happening?

```
Format$(Date - Weekday(Date, vbWednesday) + 2, "m.d.yy")
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All over the world the first day of the week is different - Saturday, Sunday or Monday in general:

[image]
*[Map from reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/MapPorn/comments/35hb3a/first_day_of_the_week_in_different_countries/)*

Thus, whenever we are writing such code, we should try to specify the first day of the week or take care of it. In the code below, I am specifying the first of the week is `vbMonday` (different from the `vbSunday` default):

[image]

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    'Sunday of the current week:
    Debug.Print Date - Weekday(Date, vbMonday) + 0

    'Monday:
    Debug.Print Date - Weekday(Date, vbMonday) + 1

    'Tuesday:
    Debug.Print Date - Weekday(Date, vbMonday) + 2

    'Wednesday:
    Debug.Print Date - Weekday(Date, vbMonday) + 3

    'Thursday:
    Debug.Print Date - Weekday(Date, vbMonday) + 4

    'Friday:
    Debug.Print Date - Weekday(Date, vbMonday) + 5

    'Saturday:
    Debug.Print Date - Weekday(Date, vbMonday) + 6

End Sub
```

Check this simulation for the first 366 days after 1.January.Current Year. For every day, it prints the Thursday of the current week, assuming that the week starts on Monday.

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim currentDate As Date
    Dim myDay       As Long

    For myDay = 1 To 366
        currentDate = DateAdd("d", myDay, DateSerial(Year(Date), 1, 1))
        Debug.Print "Today is " & currentDate & " " & _
            WeekdayName(Weekday(currentDate, vbMonday), 1, vbMonday)
        Debug.Print "Thursday is on " & _
            currentDate - Weekday(currentDate, vbMonday) + 4
    Next myDay
End Sub
```

This is what it prints:

```
Today is 29.12.2018 Sa
Thursday is on 27.12.2018
Today is 30.12.2018 Su
Thursday is on 27.12.2018
Today is 31.12.2018 Mo
Thursday is on 03.01.2019
Today is 01.01.2019 Tu
Thursday is on 03.01.2019
```

[MSDN How to Find the First and Last Day in a Given Week, Month](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh134613(v=office.14).aspx)

Comment: How do I get it to return the date in the m.d.yy format?

Comment: Was just checking my code and you'd answered with exactly the same.  @SkylarWallin - Just wrap the `Date - Weekday(Date, vbUseSystemDayOfWeek) + 4` in your `Format$` code as you originally did.

Comment: Thanks! @Vityata this `Date - Weekday(Date, vbUseSystemDayOfWeek) + 5` gave me Thursday. Does it rely on the fact that today is Tuesday?

Comment: @SkylarWallin - take a look at the added code. It tells you what it would give every February day.

Comment: The link "MSDN How to Find ..." mentioned in your answer should be https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh134613(v=office.14).aspx :-)